# EC2 created from AMI reflects unchanged private IP from Original Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I am a newbie on AWS . I did the following:

1. launched an EC2 instance
2. SSHed the instance and installed apache web server on it
3. echoed the hostname (private DNS) of the EC2 instance back .
4. created Image (AMI)
5. launched another EC2 with the image created above

I see that when I access the public ip for both the instances on the browser (http://ip) then it reflects the same hostname (private DNS) that was created on the original instance I was expecting that the private DNS should change on the second instance .Am I doing something incorrect ?

Comment: What do you mean by "echoed the hostname" and "reflects the same hostname"? What are you doing to obtain these hostnames?

Comment: echo "Hello World from $(hostname -f)"  . By reflect I mean print back on the browser html page

Comment: This might help: [Changing the hostname of your Amazon Linux instance - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html)